# Push http header into cookie

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx, apache2

I'm trying to propagate an http header across proxies using a cookie from apache 2.4 to nginx.

Apache is only around to do kerberos authentication against Active Directory. Due to the overhead that the AD authentication adds to every get request, I want to limit the authentication. The idea is to set a cookie that expires after x time and only perform the auth through apache if the cookie doesn't exist. 
Furthermore, I want the remote_user from apache made available to nginx.

Nginx listens on port 80, and does an auth sub-request to apache on port 81 (same host)

I am able to set http headers in apache, but these get lost in nginx land.

I first tried reading the specific http header that I am interested in from nginx, but I can't see it once the request is transferred to nginx, although I can see them being set on the apache side.

My second idea was to push the header that I am interested in to a server cookie and then extract it in the nginx side, but the cookie value is always empty.

In the apache conf I have:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXY_USER:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}] 
Header add X-Auth-User %{PROXY_USER}e
```

I can see that header fine on the apache side, but nothing on the nginx side.

Trying to pump the data into a cookie in apache:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.*)
RewriteRule ^/ - [env=COOKIE1:%1]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=acaprox:tst=%{COOKIE1}e:.my-domain.com:300:/] [R=307,L]
```

The trouble with this approach is that the value of test is always empty.

I also tried reusing the environment variable that I can successfully push into the header, into the cookie, but it is also always empty:

```
 RewriteRule .* - [CO=cookietest:tst=%{ENV:PROXY_USER}:.my-domain.com:300:/] [R=307,L]
```

As is probably blatantly obvious, I don't have much experience in this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be related to remote_user, other variables work with the approach I was using.

The solution for me was to set an additional header at the upstream proxy (ie, x-remote-user), and then pull the value from it if the auth_request was successful.

```
auth_request $user $upstream_http_x_remote_user
```

The $user variable can then be pushed into a cookie